# Plotly Scatter Points on Maps - Removing Longitude and Latitude from text

Tags: python, pandas, plot, geolocation, plotly

I am following this example very closely to experiment with plotting scatter points on maps and this is working perfectly: https://plot.ly/python/scatter-plots-on-maps/

However, when you hover over each scatter point you will notice the text is shown along with the latitude and longitude. Is there a way to remove the two coordinates from the displayed text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to set `hoverinfo="text"` to achieve this. Here is the relevant documentation page: https://plot.ly/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Answer (score 1):

Though lat/lon is include by default in scatter_geo and scatter_mapbox, there are two ways to customize values include in the tooltip and both use the `hover_data` parameter.

From the docs:

*hover_data: **list** of str or int, or Series or array-like, or **dict***

Passing a list/array only adds elements to the tooltip. To completely control what is displayed (in your case excluding lat/lon) pass in a dictionary with column names as keys and True/False as values. e.g.

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(data, 
                        lat="lat", 
                        lon="lon", 
                        hover_name="column_to_display_at_top_of_tooltip", 
                        hover_data={"column_you_want_displayed_in_tooltip":True,  
                                    "lat":False, 
                                    "lon":False,
                                    }
                         )
```